# Rails: how to add comment on fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I've found a piece of code, can anyone let me know what `comment:` is mostly used for and how to add comments on table name and fields?

I use PostgreSQL.

```
  create_table "sun", force: :cascade, comment: "The center" do |t|
    t.string   "distance",                     comment: "Long way"
    t.string   "energy",                       comment: "Super power"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Rails 5, you are allowed to specify comments for tables, column and indexes in database migrations. These comments are stored in database itself. You are looking at the `schema.rb` which display the comments.

Currently only ***MySQL*** and ***PostgreSQL*** supports adding comments.

Comments are simply comments - they give a short summary of what the table/column is.

To add a comment during a migration you simply add `comment: 'This is an explanatory comment'` to the migration, obviously replacing the comment text you want.

This is shown in an example migration below where I am adding a column to a table:

```
class AddSomethingToSometable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :sometable, :something, :integer, comment: 'This is an explanatory comment'
  end
end
```

For more information see the [original pull](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22911) on GitHub

Comment: Thanks for your professional answer. I also found that there is piece of code before the end of the block like this `t.index ["planet_id"], name: "index_suns_on_planet_id", using: :btree`, I know this is foreign key, but I have no idea about `using: btree`, could you help with this?

Comment: In PostgreSQL, btree is the most commonly used index type. I cant get into details in the comments because I dont have enough characters, but you should read [this](http://rny.io/rails/postgresql/2013/08/20/postgresql-indexing-in-rails.html) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) :)

Comment: Hi, I forget to add comment to fields. Is there a way to add comment after migration like when we change the type of column, we will generate a new migration to do that.

Comment: Yes you should be able to add comments during any migration that makes a change to the column, you just add `, comment: 'This is an explanatory comment'` to the end of the line where you are changing the column

Comment: I mean the migration like this `  create_table "role_groups", force: :cascade do |t| t.string   "name" end`. I forget to add comment, then I do rake db:migrate. After that I realize this mistake and want to add comment on the name field. What can I do in this situation? Can I generate another migration to do that?

Comment: You can just run 'rake db:rollback' to rollback the migration, then edit the code in the latest migration to include the comment, then run 'rake db:migrate' after that. It basically undos the migration, adds the comment and redo's the migration with the comment included

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 5.0+. Rails 6.0 added possibility to give the options `from:, to:`.

Add a comment to a column:

```rb
def change
  change_column_comment(:sun, :distance, from: "Long way", to: "Very Long way")
end
```

Add a comment to a table:

```rb
def change
  change_table_comment(:sun, from: "The center", to: "The new center")
end
```